# Why is my question considered to be "off topic"?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question, reopen-request, close-reasons

I asked this question: [Automatically reclaim my IRC nickname (without underscores) globally?](https://superuser.com/questions/483490/automatically-reclaim-my-irc-nickname-without-underscores-globally)

Without any comments it was "closed as off topic". I don't understand why. The box informing me about the close says:

> Questions on Super User are expected to relate to computer software or computer hardware within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).

Does my question "relate to computer software"? Check. There is even a [tag for that program](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xchat).

So let's look at the "scope" defined in the FAQ: as already checked, my question is about computer software. Now let's see what *not* to post:

- "videogames or consoles"? Nope, it's about an IRC client.
- "websites or web services"? Nope, it's a program to be installed locally.
- "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones"? Nope, it's software, not hardware.
- "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks"? Nope, no corp.
- "a shopping or buying recommendation"? Nope, I already use this program (and it's Free Software)

Also I think my question is "practical, answerable" and "reasonably scoped".

The box also reads:

> Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope.

I would *love* to edit my question "for improvement", but how if there is no explanation why it is considered to be off topic at all?

Comment: Wrong close reason IMO- http://superuser.com/questions/90626/kill-ghost-on-connect-to-freenode-in-xchat I think it may be a dupe of that tho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not certain *why* it was closed - my best guess would be that close voters considered IRC to be a web service.. anyway I've reopened it - since it's something that's done from client side

Comment: Sometimes the community gets it wrong. That's why there's a system to alert Moderators so that mistakes can be corrected.